# Uploading split apk files using google api client edits method in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-play-developer-api

Does anybody have any insight on whether or not the Google Play Publishing API will allow an upload with split APKs? I know there is a bundle method for app bundles, but my developer hasn't switched to this format yet.

Answer (score 0):

Split APKs are only uploadable within app bundles (whether via the API or via the console UI).

However, if you don't mean "split APKs" but actually mean Multi-APK (having more than one variant of your APK sharded by eg native code ABI) then this is available via the API or UI, and [the help page is here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks).

Comment: I did mean Multi-APK rather than split APK. Regardless, I'm not seeing anything about Multi-APK support via the [Google Play Publishing API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing) in the article you linked. I've manually uploaded Multi-APK projects to the Google Play console via the UI, but I'm unsure how to proceed regarding automation with the API [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing)

Comment: The instructions are there if you click through the docs in the link you give. Specifically here: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks. Notice that on each track the APKs is a list of version codes, not a single one. I believe each of your APKs should have a different version code. Just add all the version codes you want to the track you want.